# Setting Device Label using e2label or tune2fs causes Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda5

Tags: partitioning

I am trying to set a label to my Partitions, I used the e2label and tune2fs command
with sudo but it cause the following error

e2label: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda5
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock

What is the problem?

Comment: I would use a live cd/usb, and use gparted to relabel my partitions.

Comment: There's a good chance that partition *does not contain* an EXTn filesystem...

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem while trying to label a newly-created, freshly-formatted partition on a USB stick.

I formatted the file system and then tried to label it using `tune2fs -L`.

It gave the following error:

> tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open
>   /dev/sdb1 Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

I transpired that I had used tune2fs while the USB partition was mounted. This corrupted the file system. I couldn't even run `fsck` on it.

The solution for me was to unmount the drive, delete the partition and start all over again. This time I created the label when I created the file system, using the -L option with mke2fs:

`mke2fs -t ext3 -L labelname /dev/sdb`1

The drive now appears to be working and it has a label. But I've not tried tune2fs on it again. I was fortunate not to have any data on it. Running fsck, however, provided a suggestion that may have got round the problem.

Comment: I didn't have these tune2fs issues, and I just had to umount the device

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the partition has to be formatted in order to use e2label

In my case, I got the same error.

And after formatting, I was able to do it.